# Is it possible to import all files from a folder?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have many .css / .jpg / etc files within a folder called "assets", and I'd like to import all of them recursively. Something python-like like:

```
from './assets' import *;
```

Instead of writing a list of:

```
import './assets/img/ad0.jpg';
import './assets/img/ad1.jpg';
import './assets/img/ad2.jpg';
...
```

Is that possible?

Comment: HTTP doesn't provide any way to list folders, so no.

Comment: Are you using a bundler like Webpack?

Comment: Yep, I'm using Webpack.

Comment: @EricsonWillians Webpack should allow you to do this with some special handling... depends on the version you have. I did it with webpack 1 using `require.context`. Not sure how it would be done in webpack 2+

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in your entry point of your module

```
function requireAll(r) { 
   r.keys().forEach(r); 
}

requireAll(require.context('./assets', true, /\.jpg$/));
```

The last parameter of require.context is just a regex so you could include as many file extensions as you want. The second parameter specifies if you want to search recursively.